# How do I debug a Flask application running in a Docker containe?

Tags: python, docker, flask, logging

I've tried using the `std.flush()` to flush the print statements and importing logging library and using `logger.info()`. Neither worked.

I'm dealing with legacy code that adds a `logger.info()` statement to print to the host console, but when I try to add more, they don't print.

I am running the project using a Docker file to build the image, the `Dockerfile` copies three `.py` files needed to run the application.

I use this run command:

```
docker run -it -p 13801:13800 --net=kv_subnet --ip=10.10.0.4 --name="node1" -e ADDRESS="10.10.0.4:13800" -e VIEW="10.10.0.4:13800" kvs
```

Comment: Can you try this `docker exec -it node1 bash` after you run the above

Comment: So...I should run the container like normal with the command I showed you, and then from another terminal, I should try `docker exec -it node1 bash` ?

Comment: 1. `docker run -itd -p 13801:13800 --net=kv_subnet --ip=10.10.0.4 --name="node1" -e ADDRESS="10.10.0.4:13800" -e VIEW="10.10.0.4:13800" kvs`
2. `docker exec -it node1 bash`

Comment: Okay I have done that...I have bash open in the container that is running the application...?  But I cannot see the output from the application on my host machine terminal?

Comment: Can you call your python app any endpoints from the terminal

Comment: because I can use it to actually remote into the containers and run the application manually!